# Queue e-mail until internet connection is found when using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently developing in Unity (for a Android tablet) and have encountered a problem to which I can't find the problem. When my application gets closed, I want to e-mail a certain log file to a predefined email address. For now, everything is working great. This is the working code I've got so far.

```
private void sendEmail()
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    mail.From = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com");
    mail.To.Add("to@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "Subject";
    mail.Body = "O tempora, o mores!";

    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(Application.persistentDataPath + "test.csv");
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

    SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient();
    smtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtpServer.Port = 587;
    smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("test@gmail.com", "password") as ICredentialsByHost;
    smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    };
    // Send the e-mail asynchronously so the main thread wont hang when there's no internet available
    // The userState can be any object that allows your callback 
    // method to identify this send operation.
    String userState = mail.Subject;
    smtpServer.SendAsync(mail, userState);
}
```

Now for the hard part. Because this gets executed on shutdown, the application relies on the fact that there will always be a connection to the internet. If there's for a reason no internet connection at the time of execution, the email with the log will not be sent. So now my question is: is there some kind of way which let me queue my e-mails when there's no internet available and which will sent them as soon as a internet connection is established? But remember, the application is already closed at this point. I think I will need some kind of service (background) like solution, but I can't seem to find anything about this and I'm only just learning to code in Unity and C#. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You could spawn a background thread that has a loop that checks every minute for Internet access and when found it sends your email. However, since your app is closed the UI will be gone but the process (.exe) will still show as running in Task Manager, until that last thread finishes. If you're OK with this you could do this.

Comment: Try Polly. https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/README.md

Comment: "@Mangist" "@valery.sntx" Thanks! I will take a look at both of your proposals and see which one I manage to get working and fits my application best.